# Method won't overload

Tags: c++, overloading

I am fairly new to C++ and this method just won't overload in Vector class.

```
class Vector {
...
     void findTriDiagonalDeterminant(mpf_t *det, unsigned long long *d, double offset) {
          ...
     }

     void findTriDiagonalDeterminant(mpf_t *det, unsigned long long *d) {
          findTriDiagonalDeterminant(det, d, 0);
     }
}

class Matrix : public Vector {
private:
    unsigned long long* dims;
public:
    void findTriDiagonalDeterminant(mpf_t* det, int index) {
        Vector::findTriDiagonalDeterminant(det, dims+index);
    }
    ...
}
```

The g++ says

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Matrix::findTriDiagonalDeterminant(__mpf_struct (*&)[1], long long unsigned int*)’
```

But there's a matching function: second one from the top in Vector class.

I tried the same without pointers (by substituting *d with d and dims+index by *(dims+index)) but it didn't help.

Comment: Seems like findTriDiagonalDeterminant isn't actually a method. A method is a virtual function.

Comment: "method" is not a technical term in the C++ Standard.  Depending on who you ask, informally for C++ it can mean "virtual function" or just "member function".

Answer (score 4):

In C++ overloads in a child class hide the methods in the parent class, so only the function in Matrix can be called with a Matrix.

You can use using to expose the extra methods, something like this.

```
class Matrix : public Vector {
private:
   unsigned long long* dims;
public:
   using Vector::findTriDiagonalDeterminat;
   void findTriDiagonalDeterminant(mpf_t* det, int index) {
     Vector::findTriDiagonalDeterminant(det, dims+index);
   }
...
}
```

Comment: It didn't help. Besides I refer to it explicitly - Vector::, so wouldn't it make using redundant?

Comment: Didn't realize what line it was complaining about. This compiles for me with Visual Studio.  Are the methods private in Vector?  Do both classes have mpf_t defined as the same type?

Comment: @ArtiomFiodorov Since vector is qualified explicitly it cannot be that function call, since the compiler error mentions Matrix::function(...). (if it was the call in Matrix, it would complain about the Vector::function(...)) Post the callsite where you actually use the Matrix class to call a function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `(dims+index)` is getting promoted to something else.  Maybe try explicitly casting the result or assign the expression to an appropriate temporary variable.

Comment: unsigned long long * pointer = dims+index;
Vector::findTriDiagonalDeterminant(det, pointer);

This did not do the trick